# HTTPS connection treated differently across browsers

Tags: https, security-certificate

I am using an SSL certificate for a website and the server redirects all http connections to https (a conscious choice). A tool provided by the CA says that the certificate has been installed succesfully, but when I visit the website...

- with Firefox, the connection is initially shown as "partially encrypted" (no lock sign), but if I click on more information, identity is shown to be verified by the CA. Also, if I go to another tab and come back, the connection is shown as secure, with the lock sign displayed and the certificate correctly shown to be verified by the CA. Then, if I refresh the page or if I navigate to another page on the same domain the connection is shown again as partially encrypted. This could be a bug, but still it does happen.
- with Opera, the connection is shown as insecure and if I click on details about the connection, it says that *"The server attempted to apply security measures, but failed."*
- with Chromium or IE, the connection is shown as secure, with the lock sign displayed and everything working as expected.

Any thoughts on why the above occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely happening because your not rendering all elements on the page as SSL.

Check the source of your page and ensure that local javascripts are loading via `/path/script.js` and not `http://www.d.com/js/script.js`.

Also ensure images and every other element is secure. Simply search for "http://" in the source, this includes external scripts/images.

Comment: Indeed the problem was a `<link>` to an external font file in the header. For clarification on the behavior of Chromium and IE, I add that they did not load the external file and thus the connection was treated differently. No questions left unanswered then, thanks.